# SQL Server discarding SPACE during GROUP BY

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

Looks like SQL Server (tried on 2008 R2) is doing an `RTRIM` on columns in `GROUP BY` clause. Did anyone notice this? Am I missing something here?

The two selects are returning the same result set in the query below, which should not be the case I believe.

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(100), Age int)
insert into @t values ('A', 20)
insert into @t values ('B', 30)
insert into @t values ('C', 40)
insert into @t values ('D', 25)
insert into @t values (' A', 21)
insert into @t values ('A ', 32)
insert into @t values (' A ', 28)

select
    Name,
    count(*) Count
from @t
group by Name

select
    rtrim(Name) RtrimmedName,
    count(*) Count
from @t
group by rtrim(Name)
```

Please let me know your thoughts...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually doing the opposite, but the observable effects are the same.

When comparing two strings of unequal length, one of the rules of SQL (the standard, not just SQL Server) is that the shorter string is padded with spaces until it's the same length, and then the comparison is performed.

If you want to avoid being surprised, you'll need to add a non-space character at the end of each string.

---

In fact, checking the [standard text](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), it appears that there are two options:

> 4.6  Type conversions and mixing of data types
>
> ...
>
> When values of unequal length
>            are compared, if the collating sequence for the comparison has
>            the `NO PAD` attribute and the shorter value is equal to a prefix of
>            the longer value, then the shorter value is considered less than
>            the longer value. If the collating sequence for the comparison has
>            the `PAD SPACE` attribute, for the purposes of the comparison, the
>            shorter value is effectively extended to the length of the longer
>            by concatenation of <space>s on the right.

But all of the SQL Server collations I'm aware of are `PAD SPACE`.

Comment: Not really. So the standard claims that it pads to the max length *for comparison*, but the question is about the output of GROUP BY, which is **NOT** the longer one as you would expect if it were true that the intermediaries are lengthened (they aren't).  It's simply that `'a' = 'a  '` (trailing spaces ignored)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - section 8.2 "Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may com-
              pare as equal even if they are of different lengths or con-
              tain different sequences of characters. When the operations
              MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a grouping column, and the
              UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer to character
              strings, **the specific value selected by these operations from
              a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.**" (Emphasis added)

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to see:

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(100), Age int)
  insert @t values('A', 20),('B', 30),('C', 40),('D  ', 25)
                 ,(' A', 21),('A ', 32),(' A ', 28),('D    ',10);

  select Name, Replace(Name,' ','-'),
         count(*) Count
    from @t
group by Name

--
NAME  COLUMN_1  COUNT
A     -A        2
A     A-        2
B     B         1
C     C         1
D     D--       2
```

Notice the space between A and dot.  It chose the 1-space version over the 0-space.
Notice also that the D group chooses the one with 2 trailing spaces over the 4.

So, **no** it's not performing an RTRIM.  It's somewhat of a *soft* bug however, because it's ***arbitrarily*** choosing one of the two columns (the one it came across first) as the result of the GROUP BY which could possibly throw you off if spaces mattered.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but this might help someone else. I've used the following for the group by to properly identify differences in trailing spaces:

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(100), Age int)
insert into @t values ('A', 20)
insert into @t values ('B', 30)
insert into @t values ('C', 40)
insert into @t values ('D', 25)
insert into @t values (' A', 21)
insert into @t values ('A ', 32)
insert into @t values (' A ', 28)

select
    Name,
    count(*) Count
from @t
group by Name, DATALENGTH(Name)
```

By adding the additional DATALENGTH on the group by it will also identify the difference in length of the items.